# Find the remainder when $(3x^{45}+4x^8-5x^3+2)$ is divided by $x+1$.

Tags: calculus

1) Find the remainder when $(3x^{45}+4x^8-5x^3+2)$ is divided by $x+1$.

2) Determine the quotient when $5x^3-6x^2+64$ is divided by $x+2$.

Comment: No work of your own?

Comment: The Remainder Theorem is a shortcut for the first problem:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem

Comment: Why the upvotes?

Comment: Calculus tag? This is a 3 years pre-calculus problem.

Answer (score 5):

For the remainder, let's do some theory. Let our polynomial be $P(x)$. **Imagine** dividing by $x+1$. We get
$$P(x)=(x+1)Q(x)+c,$$
where $c$ is the remainder. We know the remainder is a constant, because we are dividing by a linear polynomial. At this stage, we know little about $Q(x)$.

But if we put $x=-1$, then we get $x+1=0$, killing the $(x+1)Q(x)$ part. Thus $c=P(-1)$.

So plug in $-1$ for $x$ in $3x^{45}+4x^8-5x^3+2$. That's the value of $c$. The calculation is easy, since $(-1)^{45}=-1$, $(-1)^8=1$, and $(-1)^3=-1$. A lot of minus signs, though, so one has to be careful.

For the quotient when $5x^3-6x^2+64$ is divided by $x+2$, it is probably best to use division of polynomials. There are tricks that one could use, but under time pressure there is no time to think of them.

To do the job properly, I would have to fiddle with layout. Set it up as a "long division." The polynomial $x+2$ "goes into" $5x^3$ a total of $5x^2$ times (the $5x^2$ is the beginning of your qotient). Multiply $x+2$ by $5x^2$. We get $5x^3+10x^2$. Subtract from $5x^3-6x^2+64$. We get $-16x^2+64$. The polynomial $x+2$ "goes into" this $-16x$ times. Continue. You should end up with $5x^2-16x+32$.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the remainder thm.

According to it, the value of

$P(-1)$ equals the remainder of $P(x) \over {x+1}$ .

So if you plug in $x = -1$ into your 45 degree polynomial, you will get an answer.

The same rule applies for the next one.